# Preserve iOS App name

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

We have an iOS (iPhone and iPad) **B2B**  application that is already working with  a specific name. We want to use the **same name** in another iOS app or convert B2B application into public one.

We have been searching in the internet and we have seen 2 alternatives, but we have some doubts with both:
**1-Delete B2B Application.**

- If we delete this App, will we be able to use the App name for other App in other developer account?
- Will the current users' installations of this App be deleted from their mobiles automatically once we delete the App from B2B?

**2-Convert B2B to public.**

- By making some changes and uploading an update to iTunes Connect, can we release the App as normal to the public, moving from B2B?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you delete the app, you will indeed be able to use the app name again. Secondly, the current users installations won't delete. They will have to manually delete the apps from their devices, as you cannot delete them remotely. 
I am not 100% sure about converting an app from B2B to public, but I believe that if you upload it normally to iTunes Connect and the select the stores you'd like to sell it in, as well as the pricing and the submit it for review this will without a problem release it for sale in select stores. 
Hope that helps,
Julian